# Проблема с транслитерацией с латиницы на кириллицу (на казахский, турецкий, корейский и другие языки)

Tags: python, функции, текст, nlp, translit

Вкратце у меня есть 2 основные колонки "name", "surname" в которых хранятся данные с именами и фамилии на латинице.

Я пробовал использовать разные библиотеки по типу transliterate, однако они на плохо работают с фамилиями как **BOLATKHANOV**, выдает как ""БОЛАТКХАНОВ"" (хотя должно выходить БОЛАТХАНОВ)
Другой пример: ** TSAI **, выдает как ""ТСАИ"" (помимо проблемы ТС, библиотеки не могут идентифицировать "I" как "Й" в определенных случаях.
Есть ли вообще база данных фамилий на разных языках?
Или же есть методы которые могут делать качественные транслитерации с латиницы на кириллицу? (функции или все что угодно, книги или методологии)

Буду благодарен за ответы!

Comment: Написать свой код не так уж и сложно, как и кажется. Просто `.replace()` в правильном порядке.

Comment: Вы уверены, что понимаете, что такое транслитерация? это _буквально_ перевод буквы в букву, что у вас и происходит.

Comment: `КHAN` в `ХАН` или в `КХАН`? Я нашёл людей с обеими фамилиями на русском. Что будете делать?

Comment: Для фамилий однозначное восстановление скорее всего не возможно. Для просто слов можно было бы какую-нибудь проверку правописания прикрутить и при неоднозначности оставлять правильно написанное слово. Для фамилий - нет, могут быть разные варианты написания кириллицей.

Comment: @strawdog Да, я понимаю как работает транслитерация. Дело в том что любая транслитерация бывает разных типов, **Строгая**, **Ослабленная**, **Расширенная**. Первая из них буквально переводят, но другие два как раз таки демонстрирует мою проблему в виде того что я не нашел нормальной транслитерации с латиницы на кириллицу. 

ослабленная : (ж→zh, ч→ch, ю→yu, я→ya…).
расширенная : (ый→y).

В интернет полно с кириллицу на латин, но нормальных с латин на кириллицу я не нашел(

Comment: @PetəíŕdTheLinuxWizard есть многие подводные камни по типу букву "Й". Допустим, если будет фамилия TSOI в таблице, то на выходе получается "ТСОИ", хотя при обратном транслитерации с рус на англ буква "Ц" превращается либо в "С" либо в "TS" (а еще I превращается в "И", а не в "Й"). Поэтому обычный .replace() будет работать некорректно для таких букв. (Еще примеры подводных камней: "KH' - > "КХ" (хотя должно быть "Х"), "tsoy" - > "тсои" (должно быть "цой"), "diyev" -"диыев" (должно "диев") и т.д.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy  в моем случае правильным будет Хан.

Comment: @insolor Но у меня все строки на латинском, нужно их всех перевести на кириллицу сохраняя при этом, целостность имени. Я не могу поменять простое имя на кириллице, а фамилии на латинском

Comment: @Setou для ts и kh - нет особой проблемы, просто заменяйте в первую очередь двухбуквенные сочетания. С неоднозначной транслитерацией i сложнее. Разве что какую-то эвристику придумать, типа что i после гласной - это всегда й (это не факт что так на самом деле, просто как пример). Для y сделать что-то типа заменять ый, если в конце слова.

Comment: @insolor согласен с ts и kh нет проблем, с И тяжелее. Дальше еще другой вопрос, как будет обстоять дела с мягким и твердым знаком? 

"Для y сделать что-то типа заменять ый, если в конце слова." 
А если Vasiliy?
Слишком много условий, и хотел бы разобраться

Comment: @Setou без понятия, нужно смотреть какие примеры у вас в данных есть. При транслитерации мягкий знак обычно на апостроф заменяется. Твердый или на апостроф, или на кавычку " (кажется где-то такое видел). В общем от ваших данных нужно отталкиваться.

Comment: @Setou "А если Vasiliy? Слишком много условий, и хотел бы разобраться" - ну тут добавить проверку, что перед y нет гласной (или iy всегда заменять на ий). Понятно что много условий, которые нужно учесть, но при такой неоднозначой конвертации по другому и не получится.

Comment: @insolor Допустим вот одни из неприятных для транслитерации: 

ESMERALDA (имя на кириллице Эсмеральда), тут нет кавычек для обозначения мягкого знака, а также первая буква Е проблематична, потому что в другом имени **ERKIN**, **Ersultan**
 переводятся как "Еркин", "Ерсултан"
Также нет слов где есть кавычки(то есть это не транслит, а транслитерация. Отличаются тем что транслит более "неформальная" и позволяет добавлять кавычки, цифры при переводе)

Comment: В общем стройте нейросеть и дообучайте её на ошибках. https://neuroinfo.ru/conf/Content/Presentations/2018/533.pdf

Comment: Один раз пытались приблизить решение этой задачи так, брали дамп википедии и находили статьи о людях на разных языках. Потом строили соответствие транслитерации имен, фамилий на разных языках. Кстати, исторически латинские имена/фамилии то транслитерировались, то"переводились", например, Augustus => Огастес/Август. Так что стОит брать те варианты соотвествий, которые "недалеко" (расстояние Левенштейна) от какой-то реализации именно транслитерации.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Что ж сразу то нейросеть чуть что )  Нейросеть не шибко то интерпретируема